# show that $\frac{n(n+2)}{2}-\frac{1}{8}\ln{(n+1)}<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{k(k+1)}$

Tags: inequality

Let $n$ be postive integer,show that
$$\dfrac{n(n+2)}{2}-\dfrac{1}{8}\ln{(n+1)}<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{k(k+1)}\tag{(1)}$$

I try use integral
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{k(k+1)}>\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{k-1}^{k}\sqrt{x(1+x)}dx=\int_{0}^{n}\sqrt{x(x+1)}dx$$
but since
$$ \int\sqrt{x(x+1)}dx=\dfrac{2x^3+3x^2+x-\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{x}\sinh{(\sqrt{x})}}{4\sqrt{x(x+1)}}$$

it seem ugly than inequality $(1)$ LHS,so How prove $(1)?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality holds for $n=1$. In order to prove it by induction, it is enough to show that

$$\forall n\geq 1,\qquad   n+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) < \sqrt{n(n+1)} \tag{1}$$
where:
$$ n+\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{n^2+n+\frac{x}{4}}}\leq \frac{1}{8}\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{n}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{n\,dx}{n^2+n+\frac{x}{4}}}\tag{2}$$
holds by the Cauchy-Scharz inequality. That gives
$$ n+\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{n(n+1)} \leq \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{4n(n+1)}\right)}\tag{3} $$
that is actually stronger than $(1)$.

Comment: I think you have some wrong  the $(2)$  is $\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{ndx}{n^2+n+x/4}$?

Comment: @inequality: typo fixed.

Comment: Very nice proof. Although, I wouldn't say the bound in (3) is much stronger than that in (1)... the maximum difference in the bounds, occurring at $n = 1$, is $8.4\times 10^{-4}$.

Comment: @TomChen: of course, the actual "strenght" depends on accounting for absolute errors or relative errors.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\sqrt{k(k+1)}=\sqrt{\left(k+{1\over2}\right)^2-{1\over4}}=\left(k+{1\over2}\right)\sqrt{1-{1\over4\left(k+{1\over2}\right)^2}}$$

and

$$\sqrt{1-x}=1-{x\over2}+\cdots$$

Comment: But this is inequality? How to use this prove inequality?

Comment: @inequality, the "$+\cdots$" indicates that you can truncate the right hand side and obtain an inequality.